# How to block a website from loading but still access its document properties.

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing a FF addon - for its particular functionality I need the body code of the website currently loaded on the active tab . For this I go the desired website normally and click the widget .... I am able to do this by the following code

```
tabs.activeTab.attach({
contentScript: 'self.postMessage(document.body.innerHTML);',
onMessage: function (message) {
console.log(message);
```

This is possible only when the webpage is loaded .Is it possible that before loading the webpage on the tab I am able to access its body.innerHTML ?

Comment: So basically you want to capture the entire HTML before it is rendered in the browser. Correct?

Comment: Nope. You can't access the content of the body element until it's rendered, and the body element, because it's closing tag is the second last closing tag in the document, is one of the last (second only to the HTML tag) to be completely rendered.

Comment: let me give you an example , like ad-block , it works by blocking the http request do some magic with the html content of it , and then render it on the browser, with no ads . Can this idea be implemented here ?

Comment: @Worlock: At least not with JavaScript as a contentScript.

Comment: guys there is an event of tab called 'ready'. Anything written in that function is performed after the DOM is loaded or ready ! I want the complete opposite of that , I want to perform some task before the DOM is loaded , is there any event for it ...... plz help !!! :(

Comment: My sole purpose is to prevent the URL from getting loaded ..... but still able to access its properties

Comment: AdBlock doesn't do any magic with content, it completely stops blocked content from being fetched. What you want to do (I suppose) is still download the page, just not execute scripts in it?

Comment: @ReubenMorais I think so yeah that will help ( stopping the scripts ) is there a way to stop the scripts ? and I want to continue execute the scripts once I return a true to that page ... maybe something like beforescriptexecutes ... but I dnt have insight to such kind of mechanisms kindly help